# Frobenius Method, Power series

Tags: sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

Im trying to self-learn method of frobenius, and I would like to ask if someone can explain to me how can we solve the following DE about $x=0$ using this method.

$$ x^2y'' +x(x-\frac{1}{2})y'+\frac{1}{2}y=0$$

Comment: Actually, I reached to

Comment: Have you started with $y=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n$, and have you plugged this into the ODE? What happened when you did, if you did?

Comment: My friend Actually, I substitute, but I failed to formulate the soultion to reach to Recursion relation

Comment: Probably because it is not $y=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n$.